# How can I apply a transformation to a mesh data with SlimMath?

Tags: c#, math, matrix, 3d, slimdx

For an example, I have position 1,2,3, rotation in quaternion 0,0,0,1 and scale 0.3, 0.3, 0.3. How can I apply it to vertices and normals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build matrices P, R, and S corresponding to position, rotation, and scale. There are likely helper functions for that.

Apply S then R then P (i.e. P*R*S) to your vertices and R to your normals.

Comment: When I apply S I receive Vector4 (the input was Vector3). Than after applying R and P to that Vector4 I just ignore its w component and convert it back to Vector3. Is it correct?

Comment: Because your full transform (P*R*S) is an affine linear transform, yes, in this case you just throw away the w component (it will always be 1). If your matrix were, say, a 4x4 projection-view matrix, then you of course would not do that.